# [Batch]: Remove language from regional settings in Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry

Would it be possible to somehow, probably in the registry, remove a language from your accounts regional settings on Windows XP using batch scripting?

If someone could point me to the correct registry key i could then just export it modified and import it with Batch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rundll32.exe shell32,Control_RunDLL intl.cpl,,/f:"c:\regopts.txt
```

where `regopts.txt` contains your desired settings.

See [this MS KB](http://support.microsoft.com/?id=289125) article for details.